# Displaying file_get_contents fails on special characters - PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to open a file with `file_get_contents`. The file contains `"` and other special characters. When I try to output the contents of that file with `echo $file_contents` in `PHP`, the operation fails with `Unexpected token` errors.

1. How can I encode such special characters?

Here is the code that gets the error:

```
<?php
//the function below displays data from bbMainPage javascript.
function getDataFromLibrary() {

    $tgt_url = $_GET["tgt_url"];
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($tgt_url);
    //echo $tgt_url;
    //echo $file_contents;
    var_dump($file_contents);
    //return $tgt_url;
}
?>
```

Code in javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.hlight{background-color:#ffcc00;}
textarea {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//mention all global variables here.
console.log("this is the start of javascript");
//get all data from the previous script.
var fileContents = "<?php getDataFromLibrary(); ?>";
var tgtURL = <?php echo json_encode($tgt_url); ?>;

console.log("URl obtained = " + tgtURL);
console.log("Text obtained = " + fileContents);   //this is where it fails.
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: File _name_ contains quotes? Or file _content_ contains them? And `file_get_contents` won't _just open_ a file. It will get it's content

Comment: The file content should not affect your php code to have syntax error.Post the code.

Comment: The file's contents contain quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with urlencode().

Comment: Not the URI, but the contents of the file contain special characters like quotes etc. I think that that is where it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't seem to have any issue with reading utf-8 encoded file and sending it to the browser. I just did a quick check to verify it. Are you sure you're sending correct charset type in header to the browser

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Where would I put this line? In the file where the php code in the question is, right?

Answer (score 0):

You want data of targeted URL.Target URL should have special characters.So first encode your targeted URL then you can get the contents of that file.

Else if you have issue in your file then you should re check the file before working on it.

Comment: I tried `$file_contents = file_get_contents(urlencode($tgt_url));`. Is this what you meant? If so, it did not work.